# How can to make required the fields keywords and description of the metatags module?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have a content type and I am interested in make required the field keyword and field description of the [metatags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module?  anyone knows how can I do it?

The field title is not required.
The field keywords is required
The field metatags is required.

I am working on drupal 7.

Thanks a lot!!

I was trying this code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if ($form['#form_id'] = 'article_node_form') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate_fields_metatags';
    }
}

function mymodule_validate_fields_metatags ($form, &$form_state) {
     if (($form['#metatags']['metatags']['description']['value']) == '') {
        form_set_error('Description', t('The field Description is required'));
      } 
      if (($form['#metatags']['metatags']['keywords']['value']) == '') {
        form_set_error('', t('The field Keywords is required'));        
      }  

 }
```

this code generate an error : NOtice: undefined index.

I have tried this code and not print dsm:

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if ($form['#form_id'] = 'article_node_form') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate_fields_metatags';
    }
}

function mymodule_form_validate_fields_metatags ($form, &$form_state) {
dsm("hello");  

 }
```

if no print hello how can test the form_state?  I don't understand what is my error.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code similar to the following in a custom module/theme:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['metatags'])) {
    if (isset($form['metatags']['description']['value'])) {
      $form['metatags']['description']['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
    }
    if (isset($form['metatags']['keywords']['value'])) {
      $form['metatags']['keywords']['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Your code doesn't work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: The code in your example would probably work if it was more like `if ($form_state['values']['metatags']['description']['value'] == '') {...`

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the code and nothing.  I tested with this code and not print the dsm, what is my error?  function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if ($form['#form_id'] = 'article_node_form') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate_fields_metatags';
    }
}

function mymodule_form_validate_fields_metatags ($form, &$form_state) {
dsm("hello");  

 }

Comment: I'm going to update your answer with the code worked for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how can I put the class error?  I tried this: $form_state['values']['metatags']['keywords']['value'][#prefix] = '<div class="error">';
$form_state['values']['metatags']['keywords']['value'][#suffix] = '</div>'; and nothing.  Thanks.

Comment: I asked in the support of the module metatags, I think is useful in this forum put this thread:  http://drupal.org/node/1782830#comment-6478322

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a nice solution, but it's possible without any custom code:

1. add a "normal" field for keywords and a "normal" field for description, set both to required
2. hide both fields in 'Manage display'
3. edit the 'Meta tags' settings to give a default value for Meta keywords and Meta description
4. set the tokens of the two normal fields as default values

To the editing user you only show the two normal fields. So don't give them right permission to change the Meta tags fields directly, they should only be able to use the two surrogate fields.