# Mapping a csv field to Meta Title and Meta Description using feeds and metatag

Tags: feeds, meta-tags

I have a csv of node data that I want to import into drupal. I'm using the `feeds` parse, and I can map the Page Title, Body, and other fields just fine. The issue I'm having is trying to map the CSV fields to the Meta Tag and Meta Description items (provided by the [metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module). Since metatag does **not** store it's information as a drupal field, I cannot map it with the feeds UI.

One possible solution I have considered is to use a metatag module that does use node fields to store meta data, but that would require a shift in the way our content editors handle things, and the installation of that seperate module on all of our maintained sites. I'd rather just use feeds with `metatag`

I'm a beginner when it comes to using the feeds api, and want to know if it is possible to write a custom mapping function that could populate metatag data for nodes from a feeds import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create fields for the metadata, hide them in "Manage display" and map them to the Metatag module (add the field tokens as content), as I described in the answer to "[How can to make required the fields keywords and description of the metatags module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42491/how-can-to-make-required-the-fields-keywords-and-description-of-the-metatags-mod/42562#42562)".

Now in your CSV import you add the metadata to your manually created fields, and the Metatag module will fetch the content.