# Best way to create HTML meta tags?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

**Issue**

Users will input text that need to be copied into (hidden) meta tag fields when the user have written them into normal fields on the input node.

What I am looking for is either a module to help me with this, a user guide to doing it or an alternative solution to the issue described in the background.

**Background**

I need to use [Meta tags quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) to annotate user submitted content on my website.

The user submit article information in normal fields (ie for example an Author field exposed on any node with the article content type). My plan is to to use the [Meta tags quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) module to create hidden fields and then have those fields filled in by copying content from the user input fields.

An alternative is of course to use the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module but I find it harder to work with and I also need to copy some other fields.

Comment: Why? If you want to copy from field A to hidden field B verbatim, why not just remove A and show B? It seems you have some requirement you didn't put into your question, it would be a waste if our answers would fail to satisfy you due to that unknown requirement.

Comment: Because meta tags are hidden in the HTML header while the input fields are displayed in the node body. I need them available in both places.

Comment: But you can do that on theme level instead. Your need does not excuse / explain data duplication at field level unless something more is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can metatags from fields on the node with

[`hook_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

e.g

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html
 */
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  // Only add on node pages
  if($node = menu_get_object('node')){
    // Read node fields, wrapper requires entity api module
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    if(isset($wrapper->field_some_field)){
      if($some_content = $wrapper->field_some_field->value()){ 
        $element = array(
          '#tag' => 'html_tag', 
          '#type' => 'meta', 
          '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'some-metatag',
            'content' => $some_content, 
          ),
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($element, 'some_metatag');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know the [**Meta tags quick** module](https://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick), but according to this [comparison](https://groups.drupal.org/node/18941) it seems to support tokens.

So the same [method that works for **Metatags**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42562/9223) should work for **Meta tags quick**, too:

Take the token of the field and set it as content for the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh.. 
You're issues is not really detailed so I will give a general answer.

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){ 
  if( $form_id == 'your form id' ){   

    $form['field_B']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['#validate'][] = 'yourmodule_validate';    

  }
}

function yourmodule_validate($form, &$form_state) {

    $field_A_value = $form_state['values']['field_B']
    $form_state['values']['field_B'] = $field_A_value;

}
```