# Meta-Tag Module that can use existing fields

Tags: meta-tags

On my node, I have several existing fields, such as `field_introduction` and `field_book_tags`. These fields were created by me and do not come with Drupal by default.

I would like to know if there are any modules, which will let me use these fields for the Meta Description and Key word Tags.

The fields I need use for the meta tags will vary between content type, so the Meta tags solution must allow local overrides.

Here are some of the modules I have looked at:

[Meta Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), [Custom Meta](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_meta) - Allows use of default Drupal fields only

[Meta Tag Quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) - Allows default Drupal fields only. Doesn't give much flexibility for selecting fields.

[Simple Meta](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplemeta) - Doesn't support any existing fields.

[Beanstag](https://www.drupal.org/project/beanstag) - This allows the use of existing fields (via tokens). But, in order to target content types, a "folder" name has to be used in the URL (e.g. `mysite.com/news/my-news` for "news" content types, `mysite.com/info/my-story` for page content types). Although the folder name can be anything, I prefer my urls to be "folder" free (e.g. `mysite.com/my-news`)

It looks like BeansTag will have to make-do, but I thought I would ask in case anyone has better suggestions.

Comment: The metatag module [supports tokens via default value](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42562/9223), doesn’t it? (and metatags_quick [maybe, too](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105367/9223))

Comment: @unor When I used both these modules, I could only get them to support tokens for default fields (e.g. title, body). If I put a token for a field I hade made, it would ignore it.

Comment: @unor The modules only work if the field has been set to plain text. Is there any way I can make it work with "filtered text" fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to:

```
/admin/structure/types/manage/[YOUR CONTENT TYPE]/display/token
```

Then make sure:

- All fields are visible (not hidden)
- The format should be "default",
  but in some circumstances, you might need to set it to "plain".

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the solution currently being worked on in [issue 1838554](https://www.drupal.org/node/1838554) is going to be a valid alternative to consider ... At least in the long run (and after the issue status reaches status fixed).